# Alexa AMAZON.City slot type recognizing minor hamlet instead of a big city

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on a skill that asks user for city names and checks where these cities are located (using geolocation service). I'm using `AMAZON.City` for `en-GB` and `AMAZON.US_CITY` for `en-US` as slot types.

The problem I've encountered is that Alexa makes strange choices when choosing among places with the same or very similiar name. An example is Brussels - when I speak it using Alexa simulator on `developer.amazon.com` set to `en-GB`, it recognizes it as Brussells (notice two L letters), Missouri, but when I switch to `en-US`, I get Brussels, the capital of Belgium (which is definitely a desired one for en-GB).

I had the en-GB version tested by a native speaker (as english is not my mother tongue) and Brussels was again recognized as a tiny hamlet in Missouri instead of a state capital.

The list of such potential mistakes is quite big: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_US_places_named_for_non-US_places

Is there a way to be more specific with these slot types, to always select most important city when multiple choices are available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing slot type from `Amazon.City` to `AMAZON.GB_CITY` fixed the problem for Brussels. The reasons might be twofold:

- while both `Amazon.City` and `AMAZON.GB_CITY` are described in documentation as recognizing names "commonly used by speakers in the United Kingdom", `Amazon.City` description adds: "This slot type recognizes common variations of city names"
- `Amazon.City` is marked as "public beta", while `AMAZON.GB_CITY` is "available" (october 2018)

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html